# Laravel Echo Listener not log in browser console

Tags: javascript, php, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

Exact the same problem like
[Laravel Echo Listener not working on frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026362/laravel-echo-listener-not-working-on-frontend)

I do not show my files, because they are exactly the same as in the mentioned question.
My `"socket.io-client": "^4.5.2"` .

I have downgraded it to `2.4.0` and `2.3.0`but still there is no any logs in the browser console in frontend.